# Merge two linked list algorithm segmentation fault C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to implement an algorithm to merge two linked lists in C++ in order to solve the corresponding [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/problem)  on hackerrank. However I'm getting a segmentation fault error message and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
  if (headA == NULL || headB == NULL) {
    return (headA == NULL ? headB : headA);
  }

  Node* currentA = headA; currentA->next = NULL;
  Node* nextA = headA->next; nextA->next = NULL;
  Node* currentB = headB; currentB->next = NULL;
  Node* nextB = currentB->next; nextB->next = NULL;

  while (currentA != NULL && currentB != NULL) {
    while (currentB != NULL && nextA != NULL && nextA->data <= currentB->data) {
      currentA = nextA;
      nextA = nextA->next;
    }
    if (currentA != NULL && currentA->data <= currentB->data) {
      currentA->next = currentB;
      currentA = nextA;
      if (nextA != NULL) {
        nextA = nextA->next;
      }
    }
    while (currentA != NULL && nextB != NULL && nextB->data <= currentA->data){
      currentB = nextB;
      nextB = nextB->next;
    }
    if (currentB != NULL && currentB->data <= currentA->data) {
      currentB->next = currentA;
      currentB = nextB;
      if (nextB != NULL) {
        nextB = nextB->next;
      }
    }
  }

  if (headA->data <= headB->data) {
    return headA;
  } else {
    return headB;
  }

}
```

The error message is the following:

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 2775]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400c94 in MergeLists (headA=headA@entry=0x1c46c30, 
    headB=headB@entry=0x1c46cb0) at solution.cc:32
32              ca -> next = cb;
#0  0x0000000000400c94 in MergeLists (headA=headA@entry=0x1c46c30, 
    headB=headB@entry=0x1c46cb0) at solution.cc:32
#1  0x0000000000400a0b in MergeLists (headB=0x1c46cb0, headA=0x1c46c30)
    at solution.cc:103
#2  main () at solution.cc:100
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) check your tags, you have C++, but this looks like straight C, (2) have you pulled out a piece of paper yet and drawn your merge out with blocks representing the nodes and lines representing the prev/next pointers and made sure you logic is correct?  Also, please provide a [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Perhaps having meaningful variable names would help. Also putting `Node* ca = headA; Node* na = headA -> next; Node* cb = headB; Node* nb = cb -> next;` on more that one line would help

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes I tried the algorithm on some test cases using a piece of paper and it worked.

Comment: What do you do when you instantantiate Node? Do you ensure you set its `next` = NULL  ???

Comment: I edited my code @EdHeal

Comment: All you have to do is make the tail of linked list `A` point to the head of linked list `B`. (Allocate memory first though)

Comment: Are you aware that, short after entry into `MergeLists()`, you do `Node* currentA = headA; currentA->next = NULL;` (and some additional similar). Whenever you pass a list with `headA`, all the next elements after `headA` are lost afterwards... (With "lost" I mean these nodes become probably memory leaks.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make your pointer "new" and then use them.
When using the new operator declares the object on the heap instead of on the stack.So you can use them out of the function.
I think you need something like this:

```
  Node* currentA = new Node();currentA = headA; currentA->next = NULL;
  Node* nextA = new Node(); nextA = headA->next; nextA->next = NULL;
  Node* currentB = new Node(); currentB = headB; currentB->next = NULL;
  Node* nextB = new Node(); nextB = currentB->next; nextB->next = NULL;
```

I hope it is will be helpful for you.
Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the segmentation fault is caused by the dereferencing NULL pointer.

The NULL initialisation of next pointer is causing it. All these '->next = NULL'  statements can be removed from below code segment. It should work for you to Merge 2 linked lists as rest of the code looks OK.

```
Node* currentA = headA; currentA->next = NULL;
Node* nextA = headA->next; nextA->next = NULL;
Node* currentB = headB; currentB->next = NULL;
Node* nextB = currentB->next; nextB->next = NULL;
```

Hope it helps!